# Teradata Event/Time triggered execution of SQL

Tags: scheduled-tasks, teradata

I need to execute a query on a teradata database on a daily basis (select + insert).

Can this be done within the (teradata-) database or should I consider external means (e.g. a cron-job).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teradata doesn't have a built-in scheduler to run jobs. You will need to leverage something like cron or Tivioli Workload Scheduler to manage your job schedule(s).

Comment: I was hoping to solve this without an external (to the DB) trigger. We us UC4 .. I'll solve it that way.